# How to remove iam policy binding of a image in google cloud platform compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-iam

It seems like that compute engine only provide a way to set Iam policy but there is not way to remove the iam policy binding.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change or modify IAM member and role settings, use [setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/setIamPolicy).

Read the current policy first, modify it to meet your needs and then set the new policy via setIamPolicy.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is the only way i can do with it.